# How to keep android device from sleeping while plugged in

Tags: android, power-management, wakelock

I'd like to keep the screen on whenever one of my Activities are running and the phone is plugged in to a power source.  I know that Wakelocks are tricky, so I'm looking for an example or some documentation on how to accomplish this specific goal.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't use wake locks for this -- just set and clear the window flag `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` based on whether the device is currently plugged in.  You can set the flag with `Activity.getWindow().addFlags()`.

So the code would be

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Answer (score 4):

A `WakeLock`isn't that tricky, just make sure to check that it isn't already held when you call `acquire()` and make sure it *is* held when you call `release()`.  You also want to make sure you have the `android.permission.WAKE_LOCK` permission defined in your manifest file.

If you only want to acquire the WakeLock when the phone is plugged in, you can register a `BroadcastReceiver` that watches for the `android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED` and `android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED` intents.  I haven't used these myself, so there may be some application permission you need to get before these intents will actually work.