# BroadcastReceiver in activity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to change the KeepScreenOn value of my activity, therefore I want to use an BroadcastReceiver inside the activity. I register the receiver in onCreate with:

```
registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"));
            registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"));
```

and unregister it in onPause:

```
unregisterReceiver(receiver);
```

The receiver looks like this:

```
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED)) {
            findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content).setKeepScreenOn(true);
        } else if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED)) {
            media=MediaPlayer.create(context,R.raw.battery);
            media.start();
            findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content).setKeepScreenOn(false);
        }
    }
};
```

No errors, it simply does not change anything when disconnecting/connecting to power source. Any suggestions?

Comment: "But it is not working at all", then what is happening ? any error/exception ?

Comment: no errors, it simply does not change anything when disconnecting/connecting to power source.

Comment: Have you tried to debug to check whether it is executing the receiver block ?

Comment: also add the permission to manifest if not added yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the defined constants, not string values :

```
IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED)
```

instead of :

```
IntentFilter("ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED")
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your registered `Receiver` actions in the `AndroidManifest.xml` ?

```
    <receiver android:name="com.app.example.firstapp.MyReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF"></action>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"></action>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"></action>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"></action>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Also do not forget to add the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS"/>
```

Comment: Do I have to register it in Manifest even if it is not a stand alone class? it is inside my activity.

Comment: try to register all above actions through intent filter in receiver.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly set debug points in your receiver to see if it's actually firing

If it is not then:

I'm not sitting at my IDE now but I think this will not work because you register the same receiver with different filters, the second will overwrite the first action.

If you want one receiver to have multiple actions you should create a filter and add multiple actions to it using the IntentFilter `addAction()` method. Then when your receiver is called, you should use the Intent `getAction()` method to figure out which action has fired.

You should also probably only register your receiver in `onStart` or `onResume`.

If it is firing:

For keeping the screen on try the solution here: [Keep Screen On Flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5331190/3312868)