# How to reset the screen timeout android?

Tags: java, android, nfc

I'm working on an android app and I was wanting to have the apps screen timeout be reset when the app reads something with NFC. The only way I can find to do this is with the deprecated field Powermanager.Full_Wake_Lock.

Is there a proper way to reset the screen timeout other than this?

Answer (score 0):

Use FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON from here:

[How to keep android device from sleeping while plugged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949917/how-to-keep-android-device-from-sleeping-while-plugged-in)

Also this:

[Correct method for setKeepScreenOn / FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331152/correct-method-for-setkeepscreenon-flag-keep-screen-on)

Comment: This will keep the screen on constantly right? I only wish to reset the screen timeout the same if the phone was touched.

Comment: You can always try it in your code. I have yet to use it. My old projects used the Full Wake Lock when I needed this feature.